# The dplyr way for creating a new variable using top_n

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to create a variable that looks at the top_n and then assigns 1 or 2 to a new variable that identifies if that element is in the top_n. I can do this really easily in base R, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it the "dplyr" way.

```
mtcars$car_name <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$new <- ifelse(
   mtcars$car_name %in% top_n(mtcars, 5, mpg)$car_name,
   1,2
)
```

How would you mutate to do this?

Comment: You could do `mtcars %>% add_rownames("car_name") %>% mutate(new = ifelse(min_rank(desc(mpg)) <= 5, 1, 2))` if I understand correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be simpler (though slightly more costly) to use `rank` (or `min_rank`) to get this directly.

```
mtcars %>% mutate(in_top_5 = (min_rank(-mpg) <= 5))
```

EDIT: I retract the "more costly" remark -- this is the same method that `top_n` uses, and thus is no less efficient.

EDIT2: As @DavidArenburg points out, this will not give the same results as `top_n`, first, because I used `<` instead of `<=`, secondly, because I used `mpg` instead of `-mpg`.  Both have been fixed above.  Also, in the case of ties, this may give more than 5, but that is true of `top_n` as well.

Comment: I didn't see the comment before I posted, but timestamps do not lie.  If @docendodiscimus wants to post their comment as an answer, I'll delete my response in favor.

Answer (score 0):

Although some very good solutions have been provided here is another:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% arrange(-mpg) %>% mutate(top_5 = (cumsum(!is.na(mpg))<=5)*1)
```

Or you can create your custom function:

```
library(dplyr)
top_n <- function(number, variable){
  return((cumsum(!is.na(variable))<=number)*1)
}
mtcars %>% arrange(-mpg) %>% mutate(top_5 = top_n(5, mpg))
```